Unable to query Trino SQL engine in the form of batch queries or multiple queries put together
I have setup my mysql catalog in my Trino engine. I am unable to query multiple queries put together in it.
For example, I want to execute below queries one by one sequentially in Trino.
update <table_name> set <row_name> = 1;

drop <table_name2>;

select * from <table_name>;

It says the query syntax is erroneous. I tried to find the correct way to query multiple queries at once in its documentation, but I couldn't find any. Does Trino actually supports this? Could you assist on this?
Many thanks in advance.

seems like a client issue to me.  I have no issue doing this when connecting to trino using dbeaver.   what are you using to connect to trino?

@TimMylott I use Trino's interactive shell running inside of a Trino's Docker container to test queries of a MySQL catalog. How do I format queries if I were to write them in a batch of multiple queries?

Using the Trino CLI worked fine for me as well.  It executes all the statements in order as long as they are separated by semicolon.

You suggestion worked and it does the needful. Here, how do I pass the batch queries in the Trino HTTP client inside of the body?

Oh, you're referring to the rest api.  I'm not super familiar with that, but I speculate that isn't possible.   From what I understand clients like the CLI, JDBC drivers, etc use the rest api and then those clients would interpret the semicolon as statement terminator/separator and send those separately to the rest api.
